# When did we learn that Slytherin's common room is in the dungeons?

Tags: harry-potter

It's commonly pointed out that Slytherin's common room is in the dungeons, which [is a rather silly place](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/199117/112139) to send them when there's a troll in the dungeons. However, did we actually know that the common room was there when we read *Philosopher's Stone* or did we learn this later on?

Comment: The dungeons are extensive. Presumably the Slytherin dungeons are unconnected from the rest of the dungeons.

Comment: and additionally, the common rooms apparently have various spells outside and within to protect them. See the portrait of the fat lady that guards the Gryf common room, and sliding staircase that prevents boys from entering the girls dorm in the same, etc...if they could make to their common room, it's quite likely the Slyths would be quite safe there

Comment: Have you read the books?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### During the events of *Chamber of Secrets*

As far as I can tell, there's no mention of the location of the Slytherin common room in the first book, *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone*. It's difficult to prove a negative, but I searched that book for all uses of "Slytherin", "dungeon" and "common" (to pick up mentions of "common room") and none of them mentioned the location of the Slytherin common room.

That means that the first time we learn the location of the Slytherin common room is during Harry's second year, when they take Polyjuice Potion to trick Malfoy.

> 'We'd better get going,' said Harry, loosening the watch that was cutting into Goyle's thick wrist. '**We've still got to find out where the Slytherin common room is**, I only hope we can find someone to follow...'
>   ...
>   'Any ideas?' muttered Harry.
>   'The Slytherins always come up to breakfast from over there,' said Ron, nodding at the entrance to the dungeons.
>   <sub>Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, Chapter Twelve - The Polyjuice Potion</sub>

---

For what it's worth, sending the Slytherins to their common room when there's a troll in the dungeons may not be that silly. The castle dungeons seem to be quite large:

> The labyrinthine passages were deserted. They walked deeper and deeper under the school, constantly checking their watches to see how much time they had left. After a quarter of an hour, just when they were getting desperate, they heard a sudden movement ahead.
>   <sub>Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, Chapter Twelve - The Polyjuice Potion</sub>